# How to manage jQuery ui tabs fx: toggle option and activate: function () at the same event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

How to manage "jQuery ui tabs fx: toggle option" and "activate: function ()" at the same event?

If you put jQuery fx: toggle fade option and activate: function at the same click event,　they stop working. Please tell me how to use them at the same click event.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs( {fx: toggle {opacity ..... } });
    // and
    $("#tabs").tabs({ activate: function () { .... } });
    // together
});
```

for the event handle of ui activate event.

jQuery and UI versions from [Google ajax hosted library](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=ja) are 1.10.2 and 1.10.3 minified.

Comment: jQuery seems to have many changes of deprecation. I was having trouble with adopting the functions for newer jQuery 1.10.2 versions. Tell me the answer suitable for jQuery 1.10.1 and jQuery-UI 1.10.3 from the above list. Many functions for the jQuery and jQuery UI do not work in different versions because of the frequent changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this way?

```
$(function () {
     $("#tabs").tabs({
         show: {
             effect: "fadeIn",
             duration: 500,
             delay: 500
         },
         hide: {
             effect: "fadeOut",
             duration: 500,
             delay: 500
         },
         activate: function (event, ui) {
             // Just for demonstrating
             $(ui.newPanel).css("color", "red");
         }
     });
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HgyBM/1/

Comment: Can you make the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HgyBM/1/) work with Jquery and Jquery UI versions 1.10.2, Jquery orginal, and 1.10.3, UI? Added reference: "Jquery and UI versions from  [Google ajax hosted library](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=ja) are 1.10.2 and 1.10.3 minfied."

Comment: It was not working earlier with jQuery 1.10.2. It is cool thanks. How to get if the element is exsist or count the tabs on jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3 since 1.9.* implementation deprecate length(), [jQuery API doc](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-length-method).

Comment: That's subject to another question then. You should close this one (if your original issue has been solved) and open a new one.